# RPi camera v2.1 not working

Tags: camera, raspicam

New camera module showed up in the post this morning and I'm trying to run some tests. Unfortunately I've got software problems straight off the bat.

I'm attempting the tests on a Pi A+. I've run `sudo apt-get update` , `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. After that, every attempt is met with:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/cameratest/sony $ raspistill -o test.jpg

mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

My memory split was 128, changed to 256 just in case and got an identical result. The original camera module works without issues. I've double checked for stickers and tapes that might be blocking the ZIF connector.

Have I missed out a crucial step somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I missed the all-important `sudo rpi-update`, which provided the firmware upgrade that I needed to run the camera. Everything's now up and running.